# officeJS Word add-in load footer with images

Tags: javascript, ms-word, office-js

We are trying to load programmatically footer/header from ooxml text. The problem arises when we have images in footer/header. We are using

```
item.getFooter("primary").insertOoxml(ooxml, "replace");
```

How can we create programatically the image relationship r:Id within document, by using javascript API?

Or maybe there is another approach for setting images in header...

Below is the xml that we get from the header:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<w:p xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main">
   <w:pPr>
      <w:rPr>
         <w:sz w:val="22" />
      </w:rPr>
   </w:pPr>
   <w:r>
      <w:rPr>
         <w:sz w:val="22" />
      </w:rPr>
      <w:pict>
    
         <v:shape xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" id="Picture 1" style="height:40.85pt;visibility:visible;width:40.85pt" o:spid="_x0000_i2049" filled="t" stroked="f" type="#_x0000_t75">
            <v:imagedata xmlns:r="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships" o:title="" r:id="rId1" />
            <o:lock v:ext="edit" aspectratio="t" />
         </v:shape>
      </w:pict>
   </w:r>
</w:p>
```

Comment: The XML you show is not complete, valid Word Open XML, in the OPC flat file format. That would contain all the information for the header/footer. What code are you using to get this XML (and in which programming language)?

Comment: I get this code from C# using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging. Is not a complete code, but this is the way I think I can show a picture in header/footer.